# how to get latest this version of MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

iam getting below error while building using ms build using jenkins but i am getting the below error ... please help me with this

```
16:41:38 Project "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.sln" (1) is building "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\NetworkFileCopier\NetworkFileCopier.csproj" (10) on node 1 (default targets).
16:41:38 c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\NetworkFileCopier\NetworkFileCopier.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
16:41:38 Done Building Project "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\NetworkFileCopier\NetworkFileCopier.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
16:41:38 Done Building Project "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
16:41:38 
16:41:38 Build FAILED.
16:41:38 
16:41:38   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.csproj : error : Version 3.0.100 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.
16:41:38 
16:41:38 
16:41:38 "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.sln" (default target) (1) ->
16:41:38 "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
16:41:38   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
16:41:38 
16:41:38 
16:41:38 "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\MetaWrapper.sln" (default target) (1) ->
16:41:38 "c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\NetworkFileCopier\NetworkFileCopier.csproj" (default target) (10) ->
16:41:38   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DeployMetaWrapper\Launcher\MetaWrapper\NetworkFileCopier\NetworkFileCopier.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
16:41:38 
16:41:38     0 Warning(s)
16:41:38     3 Error(s)
16:41:38 
16:41:38 Time Elapsed 00:00:01.35
16:41:38 Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
16:41:39 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like the .Net Core SDK is not installed on the machine